# MySQL - Join View and Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a view called "xml_links" which is in the following format

```
model_number  fk_link            sd_link
10R46         www.fk.com/10R46   www.sd.com/10R46
10R47         www.fk.com/10R47   www.sd.com/10R47
```

And a table called "prohub"

```
page_url            fk_price      sd_price
www.fk.com/10R46    $155    
www.sd.com/10R46                  $161
www.fk.com/10R47    $117    
www.sd.com/10R47                  $146
```

I'm trying to join them using the following query and all I get is a **blank table.**

```
select 
    xml_links.model_number, 
    prohub.fk_price, 
    prohub.sd_price
from 
    xml_links, prohub

    where 
        xml_links.fk_link=prohub.page_url
        and 
        xml_links.sd_link=prohub.page_url
```

I'm looking for the following result:

```
model_number   fk_price   sd_price
10R46          $155             $161 
10R47          $117             $146
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They query that you are looking for

```
SELECT model_number, 
   (SELECT flipkart_price FROM pro_hub WHERE page_url=flipkart_link and flipkart_price is not null),
   (SELECT snapdeal_price FROM pro_hub WHERE page_url=snapdeal_link and snapdeal_price is not null)

   FROM xml_links
```

But this is really a patchwork solution for a database that neesd to be normalized

### The solution that you are really looking for

Is a redesign of your tables.

In a proper RDBMS one does not have repetitive data. In your database values like 'www.fk.com/10R46' repeat not in just one table (which is bad enough but in two tables).

Secondly you are storing values in columns rather than in rows. The solution I have given you will work very well as long as you have only two vendors but what happens when you add a third vendor? YOu need to add a third column to both of your tables. That might takes hours if you have millions of records and during that time the site will be unresponsive.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. I have another column in prohub that I want to join.

Comment: for the moment you can add another correlated subquery but the more you have the slower it will get

Comment: Also I just used dummy hyperlinks. The hyperlinks are all different for each of the retailers listed.

Comment: since you are new here, may I point out that editing a question to invalidate an existing answer is something that a lot of people here get worked up about

Comment: also you need to post an MCVE, wrong information in the question only wastes the time of people trying to help

Comment: @ec45  I added this (SELECT office_depot_retail FROM outwit WHERE page_url=officedepot_link and office_depot_retail is not null) but it returns **null** in the 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

what about this, is this what you needed?

```
select
  model_number
, sum(fk_price) as fk_price
, sum(sd_price) as sd_price
from xml_links xml
INNER JOIN prohub pro
  on right(pro.page_url, 5) = xml.model_number
GROUP BY model_number;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gerardo, as e4c5 has suggested, if I have to add another column to both prohub and xml_links, the query fails

Comment: yes but that doesn't make this answer wrong (or mine wrong). your adding another column is an entirely different problem that you have which you need to solve separately (by fixing your data structure as suggested in my answer)